# Negating a closing square bracket

Tags: regex, grep

The following does not show any matches:

```
echo "A" | egrep '[^\]]'
```

If I put `\[` instead of `\]`, it works. So, how can I match a *not a closing square bracket*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bracket expressions, you don't have to escape characters, so it's just

```
grep '[^]]'
```

You also don't need `egrep`/`grep -E`, there are no extended regular expressions involved.

Your other try,

```
grep '[^\[]'
```

worked because `[` can be anywhere within a bracket expression, but `]` must be the first character. Since you don't have to escape, the `\` is actually literal, and the result would be "anything other than `\` or `[`":

```
grep '[^\[]' <<< '\'
```

won't match. In summary, to include or exclude brackets, you don't have to escape them, and `]` needs to be the first character:

```
grep '[[]'  # match opening bracket
grep '[^[]' # match anything but opening bracket
grep '[]]'  # match closing bracket
grep '[^]]' # match anything but closing bracket
```

and if more characters are involved, make sure to stick `]` to the beginning:

```
grep '[]abc]'
grep '[^]abc]'
```

If you don't, as in

```
grep '[^a]bc]'
```

the expression will be interpreted as "anything but `a` followed by `bc]`"

Comment: This is just a simplified example. Consider `[^)]]`. Wouldn't the interpreter get confused by thinking that the first `]` ends the character class definition?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, it would. `]` must be the first character in the expression, only preceded by `^` for negation if applicable.